# App Namespace less than 7 characters

Tags: facebook, namespaces

Is there any way to contact facebook regarding reserved namespaces?  Our company name is 6 characters, however under the applications basic settings "App Namespace" *must* be at least than 7 characters.

Answer (score 6):

I promise you Facebook will not budge on their 7-character minimum requirement for app namespaces.

They're in the business of dealing with hundreds of millions of people. Unless you can rally together a few million developers to make a case, you're better off just appending `ltd` or `co` or `app` to the end of your namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this for a client, Facebook won't budge. Instead we added ltd on the end of the namespace (after client approval obviously...)

Comment: Contacted them via here then the emailed us -> http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=dev_support

Comment: @reekogi Page not found. D'oh.

Comment: Yeah, you might've seen that was from 5 months ago